# Trying to keep checking value inside table with SELENIUM

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

1 - The problem

I'm using SELENIUM and Python with chromedriver and trying to keep checking a value from a table row, from https://na.finalfantasyxiv.com/lodestone/worldstatus/.

The row has a  data-tooltip="Creation of New Characters Unavailable" and I want to keep checking it until it changes to data-tooltip="Creation of New Characters Available" (specifically the table and row shown on image 1).
[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIWam.png)

---

2 - Sample HTML structure from the website

The value wanted is in class 'world-ic__unavailable js__tooltip'

```
<div class="js--tab-content" data-region="2" style="display: block;">
            <ul class="world-dcgroup">
                                    <li class="world-dcgroup__item">
                        <h2 class="world-dcgroup__header">Aether</h2>
                        <ul>
                                                            <li class="item-list
                                    ">
                                    <div class="world-list__item">
                                        <div class="world-list__status_icon">
                                            <i class="world-ic__1 js__tooltip" data-tooltip="
                                                
                                                    Online
                                                ">
                                            </i>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="world-list__world_name">
                                            
                                                <p>Adamantoise</p>
                                            
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="world-list__world_category">
                                            <p>Preferred</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="world-list__create_character">
                                            
                                                
                                                    <i class="world-ic__unavailable js__tooltip" data-tooltip="Creation of New Characters Unavailable"></i>
                                                
                                            
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
```

---

3 - Current attempt

I'm trying to store the value on 'element' using **find_elements_by_xpath** to keep checking it, but without success. How can I correctly navigate and keep checking this specific value?

```
class FinalFantasy(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        #Declare path for webdriver
        self.PATH = "chromedriver.exe"
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(self.PATH)
        self.driver.maximize_window()
        self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)

    def test_1_test_home_page(self):
        website = 'https://na.finalfantasyxiv.com/lodestone/worldstatus/'

        while True:
            self.driver.get(website) 
            #The problem is here
            element = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table/descendant::i[@class='world-ic__unavailable js__tooltip']/i")

            if element == 'Creation of New Characters Available':
                break

            time.sleep(5)

        #Add stuff to do

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.close()
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well the first immediate problem I noticed lies in your xpath here: `element = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table/descendant::i[@class='world-ic__unavailable js__tooltip']/i")`. Upon inspecting the HTML on https://na.finalfantasyxiv.com/lodestone/worldstatus/ I don't see any table elements at all and your xpath is looking for a table element first and foremost. So element in this case is going to return an empty list.

How you want to approach this problem depends on some further clarification of your goals. I assume you're looking to target a specific server to check when creation of characters switches from unavailable to available? In this case you'll want to use "find_element_by_xpath" and NOT "find_elements_by_xpath" as the latter will return a list containing ALL elements that match your xpath and you're only looking to target a single element. Beyond that there's a few different ways you can do this but my recommendation would be to first locate the element containing the server name that you want to target. In this particular case it'll be located in a div with the class "world-list__world_name". From there you will want to locate the ancestor "li" element then use that li element to locate the "i" element with class of "world-ic__unavailable js__tooltip". That element will contain the text data you're looking for. This may sound a bit confusing but it's tough to explain in a short comment here.

I'd recommend looking up some tutorials on xpath and specifically how to target elements relative to other elements. Basically you want to find target server name element (class=world-list__world_name) then find ancestor li element that contains both the server name and the character creation status element you're looking for. Then search within that li element for the status (class=world-ic__unavailable js__tooltip). If you just look for the "world-ic__unavailable js__tooltip" element directly it's just going to give you the first occurrence of that element on the page which in this case would be the Adamantoise server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Joel! I think I just assumed it was a table due to little experience with HTML. I'll read more about "find_element_by_xpath", as you suggested, to approach this problem.